# Clojure map a set to another set directly?

Tags: clojure

```
user=> (map inc #{1 2 3})
(2 4 3)
user=> (into #{} (map inc #{1 2 3}))
#{4 3 2}
```

Is there a way to apply a function to a set and return a set directly?

Comment: [algo.generic](https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic) provides `fmap`, with an implementation very similar to your example for sets. AFAIK, nothing built in to the language supports this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly more generic way to do this is to use `empty`:

```clj
(defn my-map [f c]
  (into (empty c)
        (map f c)))
```

This yields following results:

```clj
(my-map inc #{1 2 3})  ;; => #{2 3 4}
(my-map inc [1 2 3])   ;; => [2 3 4] 
(my-map inc '(1 2 3))  ;; => (4 3 2)
```

It would work for other [persistent collections](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IPersistentCollection.java) as well.

Comment: As your third example shows, `my-map` will produce results in the reverse order when given a `seq`.  It might be better to have `my-map` defer to `map` when given a `seq`.

Answer (score 1):

As Alex said, [fmap](https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/algo/generic/functor.clj#L37-L39) from algo.generic provides this function, although if you look at the source it's doing exactly the same as your code. I'd recommend just putting your function in a util namespace in your code, it's probably not worth pulling in a whole library for one function.

Answer (score 1):

With Clojure 1.7.0 (still in beta) you can do this using a transducer:

```
(into #{} (map inc) #{1 2 3})
```